# How to properly add versionable nodes in jackrabbit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, nodes, versioning, jackrabbit

im using Jackrabbit 2.0 inside an j2ee application on tomcat wtih java 1.7.
I want to version at least under the rootnode a usernode and under that a versionable lessonnode and under that a versionable filecardnode. Each, the lesson- and filecardnode holding a serialized object as property.
I am able to restore each single one, but i expected under a given version of a lessonnode to receive a frozennode that holds all filecardnodes to that time....but if i search for subnodes on that there are no subnodes.
Any suggestions what im doin wrong, or i mabey understand something wrong in specs.

This is how i save the nodes :

```
    public Node insertNewLessonNode(String userID, LessonEntity lessonEntity,
        Session session) throws PathNotFoundException, RepositoryException,
        IOException {
    //that adds a usernode if not there already 
    Node userNode = handleLessonParentNodes(lessonEntity, userID, session);

    Node lessonNode = userNode.addNode(LESSON
            + lessonEntity.getID(), "nt:unstructured");
    lessonNode.addMixin("mix:versionable");
    lessonNode.setProperty("id", lessonEntity.getID());
    lessonNode.setProperty("data", JRUtils.serializObject(lessonEntity));
    session.save();
    session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
            .checkin(lessonNode.getPath());

    System.out.println("Lesson "
            + session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
                    .getBaseVersion(lessonNode.getPath()));

    return lessonNode;
}

public Node insertNewFileCardNode(Node lessonNode,
        FileCardEntity fileCardEntity, String userID, Session session)
        throws UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException,
        RepositoryException, IOException {

    nodeCheckout(lessonNode, session);

    Node fileCardNode = null;
    fileCardNode = lessonNode.addNode(FILECARD + fileCardEntity.getID(),
            "nt:unstructured");
    fileCardNode.addMixin("mix:versionable");

    fileCardNode
            .setProperty("data", JRUtils.serializObject(fileCardEntity));
    session.save();
    session.getWorkspace()
            .getVersionManager()
            .checkin(
                    lessonNode.getPath() + DEL + FILECARD
                            + fileCardEntity.getID());

    System.out.println("FileCard "
            + session
                    .getWorkspace()
                    .getVersionManager()
                    .getBaseVersion(
                            lessonNode.getPath() + DEL + FILECARD
                                    + fileCardEntity.getID()));

    return fileCardNode;
}
```

And this is how i restore it:

```
     public void restoreLesson(String lessonId,
        String userID, String versionName) throws SQLException, VersionException, ItemExistsException, UnsupportedRepositoryOperationException, LockException, InvalidItemStateException, RepositoryException {
    Session session = JRRepository.getInstance().getSession();
    String userNodePath = session.getRootNode().getNode(USER + userID)
            .getPath();
    String absPath = userNodePath + DEL + LESSON+lessonId;
    VersionHistory versionHistory = session.getWorkspace()
            .getVersionManager().getVersionHistory(absPath);
    VersionIterator iterator = versionHistory.getAllVersions();




    LessonEntity lessonEntity = null;

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Version version = (Version) iterator.next();
        if (version.getName().equals(versionName)) {
            Node frozenNode = version.getFrozenNode();
            Value value = frozenNode.getProperty("data").getValue();

            //here i expect a few of my filecardnodes...but theres nothin...
            //i tried already with differened searchpatterns
            for (NodeIterator iterator3 = frozenNode.getNodes("nt:unstructured"); iterator3.hasNext();) {
                Node type = (Node) iterator3.next();
                System.out.println(type.getName());
            }

            Object ob = JRUtils.deSerializeObject(value.getBinary());

            lessonEntity = (LessonEntity) ob;

        }
    }

    session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager()
            .restore(absPath, versionName, false);
    List<LessonEntity> updateList = new ArrayList<LessonEntity>();
    lessonEntity.setLastModified(new Date());
    updateList.add(lessonEntity);
    lessonDao.updateLessons(updateList, userID);

    session.logout();

}
```

Any help would be appreciated....thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to retrieve the children, of a versioned node, then you must only make the parent versionable.

When you make the parent **and** the child versionable they are stored as separate `version`s so there is no link between them. If you **do** want to make them both versionable then you would have to add your own properties in order to link a particular version of `filecardnode` with a particular version of `lessionnode`.

Comment: Thx....i found a solution for that problem already by getting own VersionHistory from Subnodes. Thought parentnode knows his childsversions, but no.....Mabey you have a hint to that problem as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945095/versionhistory-of-node-disappered-after-restore-parentnode-to-lower-version-jack

Comment: I do. First, maybe you'd like to accept my answer or provide your own since the issue is fixed ;)